# Removing \r from lines read from file

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a weird problem. I read a text file then I split it using \n as a delimiter. I noticed that the split lines contain '\r' at the end. So I am trying to remove it, I tried doing so using String.Replace but without luck. Here is my code:

```
    string fileOutput = File.ReadAllText(location);
    SettingsManager.proxies.Clear();
    foreach (string line in fileOutput.Split('\n'))
    {
        string cleanLine = line;
        if (cleanLine.Contains("\r")) cleanLine.Replace("\r", "");
        SettingsManager.proxies.Add(cleanLine);
    }
```

EDIT: After staring at the code for 1 min, I found that I didn't assign the replaced value to the original string.

```
cleanLine.Replace("\r",""); //assigns a value to nothing
```

I should have assigned cleanLine to cleanLine.Replace();

```
cleanLine = cleanLine.Replace("\r","");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure running `fileOutput.Replace("\r","")` would be better than calling a replace for each of the strings attained after the split. It might fix your problem as well.

Comment: Actually I don't know how didn't I do that. I need to take some rest. Thanks Vlad, it fixed the problem =]

Comment: Thank you. A rest is always better than a couple of hours of chasing bugs you wouldn't have made in the first place ;) P.S. I would be happy if you marked my answer as the one fixing the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you call:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(location);
```

it will remove both the '\r' and '\n' from each line for you.

Comment: Arghhh, just said that too :) +1

Comment: That looks like the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how strings work in C#, and how text files generally work on Windows.

On Windows a new line is delimited by Carriage Return (\r), and Line Feed (\n)?  So, this is "normal".

Secondly, in C# strings are immutable.

`if (cleanLine.Contains("\r")) cleanLine.Replace("\r", "");` 
does not assign the 'cleaned' value.

You would need to use `cleanLine = cleanLine.Replace("\r","");`

Thirdly, from a style perspective in C# - you *should* place code blocks on another line, and surround them with brackets.   It's valid syntax not to, but it reduces readability.

As a last thing - you could simply open the text file and call ReadLine rather than needing to do string replacement as you're doing now.

Comment: Yes of course I know that I should have used cleanLine=cleanLine.Replace(); And I also know that it was my main problem and caused my code not to work. I just missed it as I haven't slept for much much time. Thanks for the constructive comment Will =] +1

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, the line indicator is actually `\r\n`, so your best bet may be to do an initial replace of "\r\n" with some other character that isn't found elsewhere in the file (like maybe "|"), and *then* split on the replaced character.  Otherwise, if you just replace "\r", you may end up replacing a "\r" that isn't actually at the end of a line (although this is pretty doubtful).

How are you reading the file in the first place?  The .Net `TextReader` class has a `ReadLine()` method, the use of which would let you avoid this particular problem entirely.

Comment: I guess there is no need for that complications. I was missing something very simple, I didn't assign the replaced string to the original one and that's why it didn't work. Thanks for your comment though =]

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead. It will split on `\n` as well as `\r\n`. Your sample can be rewritten as:

```
SettingsManager.proxies.Clear();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(location))
    SettingsManager.proxies.Add(line);
```

Comment: So why add a duplicate answer?

Comment: It's not a duplicate answer, it explains _why_ it is preferable to use ReadAllLines(), and it includes a concise code sample.

Comment: The other answer explains that too. Sample code is redundant. `SettingsManager.proxies = new List<string>( File.ReadAllLines(location))` would be better. Or `AddRange` if property is read-only.